# ''aufgeregt'' vs ''aufregend''

Tags: difference, meaning

Vor einem Jahr fing ich an, die deutsche Sprache zu lernen. Ich kann noch nicht gut Deutsch, aber ich möchte versuchen, meine Frage auf Deutsch zu stellen.

Ich verwechsle leicht die zwei Wörter *aufgeregt* und *aufregend*. Deshalb bitte ich euch um eine Erklärung.

Answer (score 8):

*Aufgeregt* is the counterpart to *excited*; in both senses, 'feeling happiness' and 'being nervous'.

> Heiligabend konnten die Kinder schlecht schlafen, weil sie zu aufgeregt waren. [=excited because of happiness]
>   Ich habe die Klausur verhauen, weil ich zu aufgeregt war. [=excited because of nervousness]

*Aufregend* is the counterpart to *exciting*: to cause feelings of interest and enthusiasm.

> Ich hatte gestern abend eine sehr aufregende Unterhaltung. [=the conversation was interesting]

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung. Ich habe hier meinen eigenen Beispiele: Ich bin aufgeregt, wenn ich jedes Mal eine Prüfung schreibe. Es ist aufregend, wenn das Ergebnis der Prüfung schon erhältlich ist.

Comment: @PinoylearntDeutsch Der erste Satz ist prinzipiell OK, wobei die Wortstellung für gewöhnlich anders ist. Entweder "Ich bin aufgeregt, jedes Mal wenn ich eine Prüfung schreibe" oder besser: "Jedes Mal wenn ich eine Prüfung schreibe, bin ich aufgeregt". Der zweite Satz ist insofern 'falsch', weil das Vorliegen der Prüfungsergebnisse ansich nicht wirklich aufregend ist.

Comment: @PinoylearntDeutsch Benutze "aufgeregt" als Adverb (*Ich warte aufgeregt*) und "aufregend" als Adjektiv (*das Warten war aufregend*). Ich denke das hilft eventuell ein bisschen :)

Comment: @Avigrail Ich glaube, du hast es ein wenig zu sehr vereinfacht. Vgl: "Die Schüler waren aufgeregt" - "Die Schüler warteten aufgeregt" Im ersten Satz ist es ein Adjektiv, im zweiten ein Adverb, aber beide Male eben "aufgeregt". "Aufregend" kann imho tatsächlich nur als Adjektiv verwendet werden.

Comment: Ja, ich habe es vereinfach, weil es in vielen fällen dieser Regel folgt. Aber du hast recht, es gibt natürlich auch andere Möglichkeiten!

Answer (score 6):

In der Schule hat unser Englischlehrer immer gefragt:

> Do you want an excited or an exciting girlfriend?
>
> Möchtest du eine aufgeregte oder aufregende Freundin?

Comment: "Meine Freundin ist aufgeregt." klingt aber ganz anders als "My girlfriend is excited."